# Pygame Error.when using display.set_model

Tags: python, pygame

This is my code:

```
import pygame, sys

pygame.init()


def create_window():
    global window, window_height, window_width, window_title
    window_width, window_height = 800,600
    window_title = "VLFA1"
    pygame.display.set_caption(window_title)
    window = pygame.display.set_model((window_width, window_height), 
pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF)

create_window()


isRunning = True

while isRunning:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            isRunning = False


    window.fill((0, 0, 0))

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

But I always get these errors:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   create_window()

and

> window = pygame.display.set_model((window_width, window_height), pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF)
>   AttributeError: module 'pygame.display' has no attribute 'set_model'

Comment: So have you read the error message? Then what don't you understand about it?

Comment: it always says  
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\RPG\main.py", line 13, in <module>
    create_window()

 File "C:\Program Files\Python36\RPG\main.py", line 11, in create_window
    window = pygame.display.set_model((window_width, window_height), pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF)
AttributeError: module 'pygame.display' has no attribute 'set_model'
>>>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you meant to use set_mode?
so your line

```
window = pygame.display.set_model((window_width, window_height),
```

should be

```
window = pygame.display.set_mode((window_width, window_height),
```

Can you try that?

Comment: THANKYOUUUUU ^_____^

Comment: Thats OK! please can you mark my answer as the correct solution?

Comment: James, did you understand my last comment? you should mark my answer as the correct solution so that others can see.